# How do I make my program stop at a certain cell?

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

Hey guys I am new to VBA for excel and I am stuck with a problem.

I am trying to do some calculations for data input and I have to make my program stop displaying values on the worksheet before "Discrepancy" reaches any less than 5. This then should make both columns "Money" and "Discrepancy" stop together. After, the program will then start in another column (column "I1" for "Money2" and J1" for "Discrepancy2") when t=10 is inputted into the formula and the values are displayed in Columns I2 and J2 until till the end.

I'm not sure how to stop it before it reaches and also how to stop the other column simultaneously. I'm also not sure if it will continue for another t=10.

Any advice

```
Sub solver2()
Dim t As Double, v As Double, i As Integer
Dim rowG As Integer, rowH As Integer

i = 0: v = 0 'related to formuala

'Range("A3").Select
'Range("D3").Select
Range("G1").Value = "Money"
Range("H1").Value = "Discrepancy"
Range("G2").Select

For t = 0 To tf Step delta
    ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0) = t

    ActiveCell.Offset(i, 1) = v

    v = v + delta * accel(t, v)

    i = i + 1

Next t



rowG = ActiveSheet.Range("G2").End(xlDown).row
rowH = ActiveSheet.Range("H2").End(xlDown).row

For i = rowG To 1 Step -1
    Dim val1 As Long

    val1 = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i).Value

    If (val1 > 5) Then

        ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i).EntireRow.Delete

    End If

Next i

For i = rowH To 1 Step -1

    Dim val2 As Long

    val2 = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i).Value

    If (val2 > 5) Then

        ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i).EntireRow.Delete

    End If

Next i



For t = 0 To 10 Step delta 'This steps it per delta input

    Range("I1").Value = "Money2"
    Range("J1").Value = "Discrepancy2"
    Range("I2").Select


    ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0) = t

    ActiveCell.Offset(i, 1) = v

    v = v + delta * accel(t, v)

i = i + 1

Next t


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the cells to appear empty, you could use [conditional formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-HA102809768.aspx) to set the text and background colors the same.

You might try a do while loop instead of a for loop to set the values in the first set:

```
  Do While t <= tf And v < 5
    ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0) = t
    ActiveCell.Offset(i, 1) = v
    v = v + Delta * accel(t, v)
    i = i + 1
    t = t + Delta
  Loop
```

I'm not sure what you intended for the other columns, but this loop would leave `t` at the value you would use if you mean to continue where the first column left off